# Proving $\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x^xe^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+1)}-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\right)dx=-\frac13$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, gamma-function

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478319/strange-symmetry-regarding-sum-sum-n-0-infty-fracnne-bn-gamman1#mjx-eqn-2_1) the OP proposed the following "Knuth integral" without a rigorous proof $$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x^xe^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+1)}-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\right)dx=-\frac13$$

I know a proof of corresponding Knuth **series** by Borwein, which used additional nontrivial techniques other than Lagrange inversion and Lambert W identities, mentioned in the post. However method for that proof is not suitable for this problem.

How can we prove it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Weierstrass definition of the gamma function might help

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2113495/44121

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution can be obtained from the formula for $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^x e^{-ax}}{\Gamma(1+x)}\,dx$ given in the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478319) (but not proven there), and the asymptotics of Lambert's $\mathrm{W}_{-1}(z)$ as $z\to-1/e$.

In turn, the formula can be obtained from [Hankel's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E2) (also [asked for](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3597563) here) $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{(0^+)}z^{-s}e^z\,dz,$$ where the path of integration encircles the negative real axis (the branch cut of $z^{-s}$).

This is done below (but I prefer to avoid references to "deep properties" of $\mathrm{W}_{-1}$).

---

For $a>1$ and $x>0$, we put $s=1+x$ and substitute $z=xw$ (the path may be left as is): $$\frac{x^x e^{-ax}}{\Gamma(1+x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{(0^+)}\left(\frac{e^{w-a}}{w}\right)^x\frac{dw}{w}.$$

Now we deform the contour to have $|e^{w-a}/w|\leqslant c<1$ on it (say, we locate it to the left of $\Re w=b$, and make it enclose $|w|=r$, where $1<r<b<a$). Then integration over $x$ results in an absolutely convergent double integral, and, exchanging the integrations, we obtain ($\lambda$ is the contour described above) $$f(a):=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^x e^{-ax}}{\Gamma(1+x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\lambda\frac{dw}{w(a-w+\log w)}.$$

The integrand has a pole at $w=w_a$, the solution of $w_a-\log w_a=a$ (here's how Lambert's $\mathrm{W}$ comes in), and the residue is $1/(1-w_a)$; the integral along $|w|=R$ tends to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, giving finally $$f(a)=1/(w_a-1).$$

So, for $a>0$ we have $$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(1+x)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\right)e^{-ax}\,dx=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}},$$ where $b=b(a)$ is the solution of $b-\log(1+b)=a$. The ability to take $a\to 0^+$ under the integral sign is easy to justify (the resulting integral is absolutely convergent, so DCT is applicable).

Thus, the given integral is equal to the limit $$\lim_{b\to 0^+}\left(\frac1b-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\big(b-\log(1+b)\big)}}\right),$$ which is evaluated easily, and is indeed equal to $-1/3$.

Comment: Hey, couple of questions: 1. Your contour encloses $0$, $w_a$ and the negative real axis where $\frac{1}{w(a-w+\log(w))}$ has a cut with branch point $0$. Why can you apply the residue theorem when there is a cut inside the contour? 2. Why are you considering only the solution $b>0$ and discard the one with $b<0$. I know it doesn't give the finite correct result as $a\rightarrow 0$, but on rigorous grounds?

Comment: @Diger: 1. The residue theorem is (really) applied to a disc $|w|\leqslant R\gg a$ without the part enclosed by $\lambda$. So the contour consists of the part of $\lambda$ inside $|w|=R$ (the $\int$ along which tends to $\int_\lambda$ as $R\to\infty$), and the larger arc of $|w|=R$ (the $\int$ tends to $0$). And 2. "$b<0$" would correspond to "$w_a<1$" which is cut away by $\lambda$. [Yes, I didn't explain why there are no *other* solutions inside, but I think it's not too hard.]

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear to me. You actually add the big circle with radius $R$ (whose contribution vanishes) to the Hankel contour $\lambda$, which (combined) gives an alternative contour that only contains the solution $w_a>1$ and not anymore $0$, the negative real axis and the other negative solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution based on some assumptions. Write

$$ I = - \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad f(x) = \frac{x^xe^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+1)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}. $$

Adopting the principal branch cut of the complex logarithm, $f$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, 0]$. Now we will assume:

> **Assumption.** The line integral of $|f|$ over the circle of radius $R$ vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

This is supported by numerical observations, and I think we may prove this by the Stirling's approximation together with the Euler's reflection formula.<sup>1)</sup> But I feel exhausted at this moment, so let me leave this part for future updates.

Returning to the computation, we can replace the contour of integration in $I$ by $-x \pm 0^+i$ for $x>0$ by considering upper/lower circular contours. This yields

$$ I
= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(-x\pm 0^+i) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{e^{\mp i\pi x}x^{-x}e^x}{\Gamma(1-x)} - \frac{\mp i}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Averaging these two representations and applying the Euler's reflection formula,

$$
I
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\pi x)x^{-x}e^x}{\Gamma(1-x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi x)\Gamma(x)x^{-x}e^x}{2\pi} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$

Then by applying the integral definition of the gamma function, we get<sup>2)</sup>

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi x)e^x}{2\pi} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-xt} \, \mathrm{d}t \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi t} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi x)(te^{1-t})^x \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t((2\pi)^2+(1-t+\log t)^2)} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(2\pi)^2+(1+u-e^u)^2} \tag{$u=\log t$}
\end{align*}

To evaluate this integral, let $C_R$ be the contour traversing the square with vertices $\pm R \pm 2\pi i$ in counter-clockwise direction and consider the integral

$$ \int_{C_R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z-e^{z}} $$

Using the observation that the equation $1+z-e^{z} = 0$ has a unique solution $z=0$ on the infinite strip $\mathbb{R}\times[-2\pi,2\pi]$, we have

$$ \int_{C_R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z-e^{z}} = 2\pi i \, \underset{z=0}{\mathrm{Res}} \left\{ \frac{1}{1+z-e^z} \right\} = \frac{4\pi i}{3}. $$

On the other hand, letting $R\to\infty$ shows that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z-e^{z}}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{1+x-e^x - 2\pi i} - \frac{1}{1+x-e^x + 2\pi i} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
= (4\pi i) I.
\end{align*}

Therefore we get

$$ I = \frac{1}{3} $$

modulo the assumption.

---

<sup>1) Stirling's approximation shows that $f(z) = \mathcal{O}(|z|^{-3/2})$ as $|z|\to\infty$ along the region $\left|\arg(z)\right|<\pi-\delta$, and I guess that Euler's reflection formula allows to take care of the remaining part by 'reflecting' the gamma function to a more well-behaving region.</sup>

<sup>2) In fact, Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem is not directly applicable due to the conditionally convergent nature of the double integral. However, this issue can be circumvented by adopting a suitable regularization technique. For instance, inserting the extra factor $e^{-\epsilon x}$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0^+$ will work, since $1-t+\log t \leq 0$.</sup>

Comment: @metamorphy, I like your approach, particularly because it elegantly circumvents the technicality that I left unproven. Nice solution, indeed!